# Airflow limit daily trigger

Tags: triggers, airflow, limit, directed-acyclic-graphs

there is a "natural" ( I mean thought parameter)  way to limit the number of triggering a dag (let say every 24 hours).
I don't want to schedule it, but some user can trigger the same dag multiple time, and for resources and others reason, I want it only once .
As I see "depends_on_past" depend only against the previous run, but it could be many time a day.
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you could likely implement task_instance_mutation_hook in the first task of the DAG, it could then immediately fail the task if you check if it's been run several times the same day.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/cluster-policies.html#task-instance-mutation